# I am not getting the desired output as required

Tags: c

The output of this program is to get the number of words in a sentence irrespective of number of whitespaces or any of the symbols as mentioned in the question.

**Here's the question:**

A line of English text will be given, where words are separated by one
of the following symbols:

' ', '\t', '.', ',' and ';'

Each word may be separated from the next and the previous by one or
more of the following symbols. You have to count the number of words
in the sentence.

Note that to read the input, you have to read until the EOF symbol is
read, as in the following example.

```
int main()
{
    int c;

    c = getchar();
    while ( c != EOF ) {
       c = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note: it is possible to solve this question without arrays, so the
maximum length of the line is not important.

### Input

A line of English text with words separated from one another by one or
more occurrences of the symbols

' ', '\t', '.', ',' and ';'

### Output

The number of words in the line.

### Sample Input

```
This is a sentence, it has words separated by spaces and fullstops.
```

### Sample Output

```
12
```

I know I have to use the format given in the question, but I didn't know how to use it.

I only know the program to find number of words in a sentence when the words are separated by only single space or a single \t. But, I didn't get any idea to solve this question.

Comment: As you interate through the chars, they are in the set of [' ', '\t', '.', ',' and ';'], or they are not.  Also, you are either currently 'in a word' or 'not in a word', and that state can be changed by the char you are inspecting.  If the state changes to 'in a word', increment your word count.

Comment: Of course you don't get the desired output, because your program does basically nothing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP has done nothing to satisfy the requirements of the assignment.

Comment: The assignment sucks anyway.  I mean, I would immediately want to initialize a static const array of those 'not in a word' chars, (with a NUL terminator), so it can be seached through to decide whether any given char is part of a word or not:(  Without arrays, it means a case switch or if/else ladder:(

Comment: @MartinJames  As far as the "it is possible to solve this question without arrays" comment in the problem goes, I'm assuming it says that to discourage students from first reading the input into an array and then parsing it. I don't think it's trying to discourage students from using arrays to implement the input stream parsing logic.

Comment: @phonetagger you're probably right, but the prof/TA/OP should be clear on the matter.  Searching an array is neater and cleaner than alternatives, and could be made more flexible, eg. by loading the 'non-word' array from a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple application of four elements.

1. while()
2. getchar()
3. switch()
4. printf()

the following code shows one way to implement the function:

```
#include <stdio.h>  // getchar(), EOF, printf()

int main( void )
{
    int wordCount = 0;
    int ch;
    int inWord = 0;

    while( (ch = getchar()) != EOF )
    {
        switch( ch )
        {
            case ' ':
            case '\t':
            case '.':
            case ',':
            case ';':
                inWord = 0;
                break;

            default:
                if ( !inWord )
                {
                    wordCount++;
                    inWord = 1;
                }
                break;
        } // end switch
    } // end while

    printf( "\n%d\n", wordCount );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[one of delimiters]...[one of delimiters][not one of delimiters]... 
                                        ^^ count this edge.
```

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool IsDelimiter(char ch, const char *delimiters){
    while(*delimiters)
        if(*delimiters++ == ch)
            return true;
    return false;
}

int main(void){
    bool prev_is_delmiter = true;
    int ch, wc = 0;

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n'){
        bool current_is_delmiter = IsDelimiter(ch, " \t,.;");
        if(prev_is_delmiter && !current_is_delmiter){
            ++wc;
        }
        prev_is_delmiter = current_is_delmiter;
    }
    printf("%d\n", wc);
}
```

Comment: Good answer: Counting the "edge" is the best idea as it handles the first and last word well with their optional leading/tailing delimiters.